# Meta tags not valid (html5reset templates)

Tags: validation, meta-tags, dublin-core

I am using html5reset as a reset and template for a website. However I am getting all kinds of validation errors on some meta tags:

```
<meta name="title" >
<meta name="google-site-verification" >
<meta name="copyright" >
<meta name="DC.title" >
<meta name="DC.subject" >
<meta name="DC.creator" >
```

I could simply remove those meta tags, but I'd rather know why first. Here is the link to validate my website (which is online at a temporary url): http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Ftanchelmus.be%2Fsten%2Fnl%2Fnews&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

Comment: HTML 5 Validator does not seem to recognize the name="title" for me as well....wtf...that seems like the most basic one?

Comment: in html 5 title is it's own tag, <title>My title</title>.  Looks like only `application-name`, `author`, `description`, `generator`, `keywords` options for `name` are supported out of the box http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_meta.asp

Answer (score 2):

If you use "property" instead of "name" you will pass HTML5 validator.

```
<meta property="DC.title" >
<meta property="DC.subject" >
<meta property="DC.creator" >
```

I'm not entirely sure if the syntax is correct, but I did see this in RDFa documentation here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RDFa

Comment: Actually, the construction is more like <meta property="dc:creator" content="Jonathan Doe" />, which in effect uses xml prefixes, defined at the top of the document: <html prefix="dc: http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" lang="en">

Answer (score 1):

Another thing to note is that the HTML5 standard is a work in progress.  And thus the W3C HTML5 validator is also a work in progress.

This [blog post](http://blog-lounge.org/html5-microformats-schema/) has some interesting background regarding Microformats (eg Dublin Core) & HTML5.

It may not always be pragmatic to develop just to please the Validator, especially one that is a work in progress.

Answer (score 0):

What it looks like you're being told is that the values you're using in the `name` attribute are not part of the valid set of values you can use.

Ths [WhatWG Website](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/semantics.html#standard-metadata-names) identifies many of the standard and other meta name values.

Comment: I have looked at that, but it seems like for example: DublinCore meta tags are still useda lot, so what's the benefit of them if they are not valid?

Answer (score 0):

Hello to validate the Dublin Core tags, you must change dc. to dcterms.
Here you can see an example:
`<meta name="dcterms.contributor" content="Your name" />
<meta name="dcterms.keywords" content="Your keywords here" />`

Regards!